# Migrate Azure App Service on Wordpress to another with same configuration different database

Tags: wordpress, azure, azure-appservice, appservice

I have a Azure App Service on Wordpress, i want to migrate in the same tenant with same configuration but connected to another database, so the content on the wordpress shouldnt be the same. Using plugins from wordpress is not an viable option, the documentation saids i cannot "clone" an app service via cli but maybe i missed something.

How can i do this? It its possible through AZ CLI? Or its needed to be via ARM template?

I have tried to download the ARM template but there are some resources that can be exported since it depends from others services which i cant export

Comment: You want to move the configurations to another App Service ?

Comment: Yes, thats correct

Comment: Refer this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/587234/migrating-moving-azure-wordpress-app-service-to-an) once